# How to set time and memory limit?

Tags: python, docker, compiler-errors, dockerfile, docker-swarm

Hello,
I'm working on online judge project and i'm using docker container for running a user code.
So, when user submit the code, that code runs in a docker container and then it returned output back to user.
Below is the code, how I am handling the user code by running on docker container.

```
        data = loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
        //writing user code and custom input to file
        write_to_file(data['code'], "main.cpp")
        write_to_file(data['code_input'], "input.txt")

        # Uncomment below 3 lines if below image is not installed in local
        # print("building docker image")
        # p = getoutput("docker build . -t cpp_test:1")
        # print(p)

        containerID = getoutput("docker run --name cpp_compiler -d -it cpp_test:1")
        
        # uploading user code on running container
        upload_code  = getoutput("docker cp main.cpp cpp_compiler:/usr/src/cpp_test/prog1.cpp")
        upload_input = getoutput("docker cp input.txt cpp_compiler:/usr/src/cpp_test/input.txt")

        result = getoutput('docker exec -it cpp_compiler sh -c "g++ -o Test1 prog1.cpp && ./Test1 < input.txt" ')
        print("Deleting the running container : ",getoutput("docker rm --force cpp_compiler")) 

        return JsonResponse(result)
```

Now, I want to set time and memory limit on users code, like when the code will be taking more than expected time or memory, it will throw TLE or out of memory error.
I'm not getting the correct way of implementation.
I'm new in this field, any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to control memory with [docker options](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/), and time with python thread.

Comment: Thanks @Balaïtous , But if there are 10 test cases for a particular problem, so 10 threads will running simultaneously in a container, for time limit, as you said , I can control time limit with python thread, but for memory, how can i handle memory for each thread using docker option? Is there also any docker option for memory control for each thread also?

Comment: I think you should put time limit for the `docker exec` command and stop container if time exceed limit.

Comment: Hope this can be useful: http://coldattic.info/post/40/

Comment: @Balaïtous, Thankyou so much, I will go through the above mentioned link once.